# jquery picklist: once deselect an item, it can't be selected anymore

Tags: jquery, picklist

It looks like if you deselect an item from the "selected" list, then you can't change your mind and select it again.
It is clear also in the "form" example provided by the website:

http://jsfiddle.net/awnry/QzjTs/

if you deselect the items 2 or 4, and then you select them again, they move correctly from the left to the right, but their "selected" attribute doesn't change, and indeed they are not listed in the "form content" box.

( You can also verify the count of selected items with:

```
function updateConsole()
{
    $("#console").text($("#form option:selected").length);
}
```

)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

**EDIT: looks like it works fine with Chrome, while it doesn't work with FF or MSIE. Maybe it needs a fix...?**

Comment: working fine for me - Chrome v 21

Comment: I could not get what is your Question ?

Comment: @Elen: have you seen the provided example? It doesn't work neither with FF23 nor with MSIE.10, while it works with Chrome

Comment: yes i tested your jsfiddle in Chrome and it works fine. didn't test anywhere else

Comment: @sudhAnsu63: the Question is: how can I fix the above reported misbehavior of this plugin?

Comment: Never mind  your worked for me in Chrome. I got the after your edit .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works well in jQuery 1.8.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QzjTs/57/

The reason why is that in order to work well in jQuery 1.9 + the plugin must be updated in `.removeAttr("selected")` to `.removeProp("selected")`;
and `.attr("selected", "selected");` to `.prop("selected", "selected");`

Update guide: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Issue here: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/issues/detail?id=16

Comment: I would give +5 if I could; this fixed a similar problem for me.  This is a great reason why including the meat of the explanation is important.  Today (Feb'18) the `code.google.com` link is broken.  To anyone else finding this, just do a search and replace on `removeAttr` and `.attr(`, and replace with `removeProp` and `.prop(`.